# How can I make method dynamically load key/value pairs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I take this code and make it more dynamic?

Right now I have to post JSON as

```
{ values: [{Key: 'MyKey', Value: 'MyValue'}] }
```

Ideally I would like to post JSON like:

```
    { values: [{Make: 'Car', Color: 'Red'}] }
OR
    { values: [{FirstName: 'George', LastName: 'Constanza'}] }
```

So basically I am tied to using Key/Value in my JSON. 
 How can I dynamically load the values without having to use Key/Value?

```
public class MyPerformerController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut("update/{myPath}")]
    public Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(string myPath, [FromBody]MyCollection values)
    {
        foreach (var val in value)
        {
            var keyValue = val.Key;
            var someValue = val.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class MyCollection : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
{ 
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Values { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Recieve it as a string and deserialize to `dynamic` or `JObject` and parse on controller

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this? In any case you have to make a specific logic for each controller/action, but in that case you just rejecting basic data validation, in case when you'll use stricktly typed objects you'll got the data validation and conversion logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had this structure:

```
[{FirstName: 'George', LastName: 'Constanza'}]
```

You can convert to `JArray` using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);`

For instance, having this json:

```
[
    {
        FirstName: "George",
        LastName: "Constanza"
    }, {
        FirstName: "Mike",
        LastName: "Passant"
    }, {
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Connor"
    }
]
```

You can iterate and get the `Key` and the `Value`:

```
JArray jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

foreach (JObject item in jsonArray.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty element in item.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0}", element.Name));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value: {0}", element.Value.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Here you can see a <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/WBJ47851)</kbd>.

Comment: I get an invalid cast on this line

JArray jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

Comment: @PrivateJoker I think it's because you are using `values:` and I'm using `"values":` (with quotes). Also I'm replacing the first `{` and the last `}`. Maybe reviewing the demo is more clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `FromBody` with dynamic type. See an example below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/webs/")]
        public HttpResponseMessage RouteGetWebList([FromBody]dynamic values)
        {

            string myVar = (string)values["myJSONVariable"].Value;

             // go on with myVar...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you declare it as a `List<IDictionary<string,string>> values`, you'll get a data structure similar to what you desire.  Where you can access `list[0]["FirstName"]` or similar.